# When I am trying to run ejabberdctl live, it is taking almost 30 minutes to load configuration

Tags: ejabberd

I am passing the below run level commands while running ejabberdctl live.  After passing those commands it's taking almost 30 minutes to load configuration.

After that, I  am trying to run another application, i.e Tsung, to load to ejabberd but it's not running

Answer (score 0):

30 minutes while loading the configuration? Or maybe it's 30 minutes loading the internal mnesia database content?

If you think it's the configuration file, you can try disabling options and modules until you find which one is responsible for the slow start. Or you can put the default configuration file, that one should be very fast to start.

If you consider that the slow start is caused big internal Mnesia database, you can make this test: stop ejabberd, move the internal mnesia database files to another directory (so ejabberd doesn't use them), then start ejabberd. This way ejabberd will start with an empty internal mnesia database, that must be very fast to start. If that solves your problem, then you can be sure the problem is in your database.

Comment: there is no data in internal data base

Comment: am facing problem when am paasing the ulimit -n 20000000 at that time only its taking mre than 30 mins

Comment: at the same time tsung also not responding after  passing ulimit value its section automatically aborting